# How can I format and use Custom labels with tokens in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, customlabel

I'm migrating from Aura component into LWC component.

Trying to find a standard replacement statement in lwc to replace custom labels tokens with dynamic values.

Custom Label Value:

```
"Range Between {0} to {1}"
```

in Aura I could do :

```html
{!format($Label.c.MyCustomLabel, v.value1,v.value2)}
```

How should I do it in lwc?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Currently, there is no native solution for replacing custom labels tokens with dynamic values in LWC. But you can implement similar functionality using pure js.
Let's create some service LWC component `IntlService` to be able to reuse its functionality from everywhere:

```js
class IntlService {

    static format(stringToFormat, ...formattingArguments) {
        if (typeof stringToFormat !== 'string') throw new Error('\'stringToFormat\' must be a String');
        return stringToFormat.replace(/{(\d+)}/gm, (match, index) =>
            (formattingArguments[index] === undefined ? '' : `${formattingArguments[index]}`));
    }

}

export { IntlService };
```

So now,  we can import this module into our LWC component and all the features of this module are now at our disposal:

```html
<template>
    {label}
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import Placeholder from '@salesforce/label/c.Placeholder'; /*{0} lives in {1}.*/
import { IntlService } from 'c/intlService';

export default class Component extends LightningElement {

    firstName = 'Jim';
    city = 'London';

    get label() {
        return IntlService.format(Placeholder, this.firstName, this.city);
    }

}
```

Result:

```
Jim lives in London.
```

In this case, all the magic is performed by the [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method which returns a new string with some or all matches of a `pattern` replaced by a `replacement`. The `pattern` can be a `string` or a `RegExp`, and the `replacement` can be a `string` or a `function` to be called for each match.